# How to install Flutter on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

In fact I'm alsmost done with the installation, The only issue is when I run `flutter doctor` I get this error report :

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 27.0.1)
    ✗ Flutter requires Android SDK 28 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
      To update using sdkmanager, run:
        "/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager" "platforms;android-28"
        "build-tools;28.0.3"
      or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      detailed instructions.
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

As I said  i'm working on Ubuntu 20.04 , Andrroid studion is installed:
[SDK settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqvuN.png)

Answer (score 0):

It says that you are using Android SDK version 27.0.1.But flutter required Android BuildTools 28.0.3. Updating Android Studio version's full instruction here:https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update

After update your android studio version,Run

> $ flutter doctor

then flutter doctor will tell you to run a command for android studio license agreement.
Simply run the command and type y to continue and then you have done!{**Telling from my personal experience**}

Thank you.